# React native async storage returning previous value

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm using react-native-async-storage for saving API headers and user information received from API

```
const storeUserInfo = async (userInfo: any, headers: any) => {
  console.log(
    'Info Received in Local Storage Function',
    userInfo,
    'Headers Received in Local Storage Function',
    headers,
  );

  try {
    const user = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
    const userheaders = JSON.stringify(headers);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', user);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('headers', userheaders);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error while storing user info', e);
  }
};
```

when i try to get headers from async-storage, it gave old stored headers rather than returning latest.

// Getting headers like this..

```
const headers = await AsyncStorage.getItem('headers');
console.log('Headers received in get Profile Action', headers);
```

but it returning old headers..

Comment: maybe you can use callback functions in setItem to see if you call getItem after completion. Because some say that await does not work properly here so can't sure data saved right after the execution.

Comment: yes , the issue is that
I set user first and async storage was not setting headers.
means it doesn't execute line where I was setting headers

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but React native async storage is not running next line after the setItem line

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', user);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('headers', userheaders);
```

setItem for a user is running but setItem for a header is not running and that's why it was returning old value

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below approach to fetch the data.

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const headers = await AsyncStorage.getItem('headers')
    return headers != null ? JSON.parse(headers) : null;
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Comment: it gives same old header value